# Сохранение HorizontalScrollView в изображение в Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Хочу сохранить представление как картинку, он состоит из множества элементов, в том числе HorizontalScrollView  и ScrollView. Я делаю следующее: родитель ScrollView у него дочерний LinearLayout (id/ResultQToPDF) который в сохраняю в картинку. В сохраняемом LinearLayout содержится в том числе и HorizontalScrollView. В итоге картинка получается обрезанной сбоку, то есть часть HorizontalScrollView отсутствует, а по вертикали сохраняет корректно.

[image: Результат]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/strScrollQ"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/no_press_back"
tools:context="com.polyhydro.prk.OutputResultsFindQ">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ResultQToPDF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/strQ0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleFQ"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ ПРОПУСКНОЙ СПОСОБНОСТИ"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/strQ2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Серия трубопровода"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/diameterSeries_outputFQ"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

      

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strQ9"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                        android:text="Коэффициент\nнаполнения"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strQ10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                        android:text="Расход\nжидкости"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strQ11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                        android:text="Скорость\nжидкости"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strD10FQAlter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                        android:text="Расход\nжидкости"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_alt_no_press"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strD11FQAlter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                        android:text="Скорость\nжидкости"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_alt_no_press"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </TableRow>
```

Код сохранения

```
private boolean saveBitMap(View drawView) {
    Date dateNow = new Date();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatForDateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm dd.MM.yyyy");

    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File dir = new File(root + "/Отчеты PolyHydro");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    String fileName = formatForDateNow.format(dateNow);
    File file = new File(dir, "Отчет PolyHydro FindD " + fileName + ".jpg");

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(drawView);
    try {
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, oStream);
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
        galleryAddPic(file);
        /*     openImage(pictureFile);*/
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка сохранения: что-то пошло не так", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
 private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Запоминаем старые значения цветов, чтобы присвоить их обратно после экспорта
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int oldTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.text_color);
    int oldBackgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.no_press_back);
    for (TextView textView : textList) textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    if (PressFindHend.isAltMaterialNeeded) {
        for (TextView textView : textListAlter) textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    findViewById(R.id.strScrollD).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null) {
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    view.draw(canvas);
    for (TextView textView : textList) textView.setTextColor(oldTextColor);
    if (PressFindHend.isAltMaterialNeeded) {
        for (TextView textView : textListAlter)
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_alt_no_press));
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    findViewById(R.id.strScrollD).setBackgroundColor(oldBackgroundColor);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    return returnedBitmap;

}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял - вы хотите сделать своего рода скриншот содержимого ScrollView. При этом внутри у вас горизонтальный ScrollView. Коли так, то вам, по идее, надо сделать отдельно скрин горизонтального ScriollView, отдельно вертикального (по возможности без горизонтального). После этого надо программно склеить обе картинки. Будет гораздо проще, если горизонтальный находится в самом начале или в самом конце вертикального, а не посередине.

Comment: Юрий, спасибо, вы все правильно поняли

Comment: Покажите код сохранения. Ощущение, что все нормально вывелось бы, если бы вы правильно посчитали (увеличили) ширину.

Comment: Yura Ivanov, дополнил код

Comment: Сорри, не увидел ответ. Отвечайте через @ тогда ответ на комментарий попадет в уведомления.
Что касается сохранения, то `view.getWidth()` говорит о том, что вы берете ширину view, ну и она конечно меньше чем нужно. Попробуйте явно указать размеры для теста существенно больше. И чтоб точно посчитать ширину надо циклом будет пробежаться по всем child'ам (рекурсивно) и посчитать максимальную ширину... Проблемы могли бы возникнуть, например, если бы у вас был recyclerview, тогда пришлось бы явно получать элементы через createViewHolder/bindViewHolder и вручную рисовать их через draw...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вот я указал размер сильно больше экрана, но оставшеся место заполняется пустым местом. Не подскажете как мне "прокрутить в сторону" HorizontalScrollView